# Using EXEC() AT [Linked Server] for Insert data from local server

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, linked-server

let me first explain a little abot my setup before letting you know the issue Im dealing with:

I have two database servers: SQL 2008 and MySql. I have a procedure in SQL that first, deletes a table in MySql and then populates it with some data from the SQL itself. For both actions im using OPENQUERY. But, as you know, it doesnt know support large data. It becomes really slow eventhou for truncating the table in MySql (it was taking like 14 minutes to delete 60k rows... insane!).

So i found out i could use this syntax for truncating:

***EXEC ('TRUNCATE TABLE table_name') AT LINKEDSERVER***

But i havent been able to find the syntax for inserting the results of the SQL table to my MySql table thru this. It works correct when I insert static data, like this example:

***EXEC ('INSERT INTO table_name (row1, row2) VALUES (value1, value2)') AT LINKEDSERVER***

But I want to insert the results from a SQL, as I said, something like this:

***EXEC ('INSERT INTO table_name (row1, row2) SELECT r1, r2 FROM SQL_DB.sql_table_name') AT LINKEDSERVER***

I bet that i cannot do it because in that syntax, Im executing the exec in the MySql server and the SQL table doesnt exist there. So how can i referrence my SQL table inside the "EXEC() AT" syntax?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to use EXEC() AT? Why not INSERT LINKEDSERVER...tablename SELECT ... FROM ...?

Comment: > So how can i referrence my SQL table inside the "EXEC() AT"
In short, you can not, the query executed by EXEC (with or without AT) is running in a different scope (in your case this is on MySQL) and you can not access the tables in SQL Server from MySQL. You stuck with OPENQUERY, or you can generate an INSERT INTO statement (dynamic query using strings) and exec that on the MySQL server, however this should be plan Z. **What about an SSIS package instead of linked servers?**

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Ive told told to use SISS but I havent tried it yet since I dont have that module on this SQL server. I was trying to make it work thru LinkedServer.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I cant get INSERT LINKEDSERVER...tablename SELECT ... FROM ... to work. I have not been able to reference a LinkedServer without OPENQUERY or that EXEC() AT so far.

Comment: What does "can't get to work" mean? Many other people have functional linked servers to MySQL from SQL Server. Anyway I agree with Pred, if the underlying issue is that you're moving a *lot* of data from SQL Server to MySQL, I would avoid linked servers / EXEC AT / OPENQUERY anyway. Don't try to use a tricycle to do the work of a dump truck.

Comment: Alrite, thank you both! Ill stop using LinkedServers and check out SISS.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use "OPENQUERY" to do this - see

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
INSERT INTO [LinkedServer].Database.Schema.Table(Attributes)
From
Select (attributes) from Database.Schema.Table as TableAlias
```